# Question about C programming

Tags: c, operators

```
int a, b;
a = 1;
a = a + a++;
a = 1;
b = a + a++;

printf("%d %d, a, b);
```

output : 3,2

What's the difference between line 3 and 5?

Comment: This looks rather convoluted. I would have expected the output to be 2,2.

Comment: Line 3 isn't valid standard C, that's one difference =)

Comment: -1 This code can't work in the way described (the undefined behavior is irrelevant). The value in 'a' is discarded on the second 'a = 1;' (thus a should be '2' because the only code modifying it after that point is the single 'a++'). Furthermore (after a slightly closer look), this code won't even compile as the string in the 'printf' statement is never closed.

Comment: @Stephen: Line 5 too isn't valid standard C

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are doing is undefined.

You can't change the value of a variable you are about to assign to.

You also can't change the value of a variable with a side effect and also try to use that same variable elsewhere in the same expression (unless there is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), but in this case there isn't). The order of evaluation for the two arguments for + is undefined.

So if there is a difference between the two lines, it is that the first is undefined for two reasons, and line 5 is only undefined for one reason. But the point is both line 3 and line 5 are undefined and doing either is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing on line 3 is undefined. C++ has the concept of "sequence points" (usually delimited by semicolons). If you modify an object more than once per sequence point, it's illegal, as you've done in line 3. As [**section 6.5 of C99**](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) says:

> (2) Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

Line 5 is also undefined because of the second sentence. You read `a` to get its value, which you then use in another assignment in `a++`.

Comment: Probably you missed "Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored."

Answer (score 4):

Line 3 is undefined, line 5 is not.

### EDIT:

As Prasoon correctly points out, **both** are UB.

The simple expression `a + a++` is undefined because of the following:

1. The operator `+` is not a sequence point, so the side effects of each operands may happen in either order.
2. `a` is initially `1`.
3. One of two possible [sensible] scenarios may occur:

   1. The *first* operand, `a` is evaluated first,

      a) Its value, `1` will be stored in a register, `R`. No side effects occur.

      b) The second operand `a++` is evaluated. It evaluates to 1 also, and is added to the same register `R`. As a side effect, the stored value of `a` is set to 2.

      c) The result of the addition, currently in `R` is written back to `a`. The final value of `a` is 2.
   2. The *second* operand `a++` is evaluated first.

      a) It is evaluated to `1` and stored in register `R`. The stored value of `a` is incremented to `2`.

      b) The first operand `a` is read. It now contains the value `2`, not `1`! It is added to `R`.

      c) `R` contains `3`, and this result is written back to `a`. The result of the addition is now `3`, not `2`, like in our first case!

In short, you mustn't rely on such code to work at all.

Comment: Probably you missed "Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored."

Answer (score 4):

`a++` is a post-fix operator, it gets the value of a **then** increments it.

So, for lines 2,3:
a = 1
a = 1 + 1, a is incremented.
a becomes 3 *(Note, the order these operations are performed may vary between compilers, and a can easily also become 2)*

for lines 4,5:
a = 1
b = 1 + 1, a is incremented.
b becomes 2, a becomes 2. *(Due to undefined behaviour, b could also become 3 of a++ is processed before a)*

Note that, other than for understanding how postfix operators work, I really wouldn't recommend using this trick. It's [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and *will* get different results when compiled using different compilers

As such, it is not only a needlessly confusing way to do things, but an unreliable, and worst-practice way of doing it.

**EDIT**: And has others have pointed out, this is actually undefined behavior.

Comment: Thx A LOT! xD // that code was just for an educational purpose

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it does not mention "undefined behaviour", which is what you are invoking.  The explanation is bogus, too - I am sorry to say.  There is no good explanation because the standard says the behaviour is undefined - anything is legitimate.

Comment: Concurrence with Jonathan -- it's not merely that this is "needlessly confusing", but it's actually wrong to do it. The standard does not allow modifying things twice between sequence points.

Comment: Updated to reflect that this behavior is undefined. The first sequence of events still adequately explains what happened using his compiler.

Comment: @Adam: Giving explanation of an undefined behavior doesn't make much sense. You should have given just the reason why these expressions invoke undefined behavior. Mark's answer is totally correct.

Comment: -1, this is undefined behavior according to the standards, full stop. Giving explanation of such a trivial case out of the umpteen possibilities which themselves are compiler specific is ridiculous