# C Programming #define?

Tags: c, macros, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define SQ(x) x*x

void main()
{
   int a1 , a2;
   int b1 , b2;

   a1 = 2;
   a2 = 2;

   b1 = 0;
   b2 = 0;

   b1 = SQ(a1++);
   b2 = SQ(++a2);

   printf("Frist = %d",b1);
   printf("Second = %d",b2);
}
```

I know what is the output of the code.

as #define work in  other programe
that way it is not working in above code
Why.?

Comment: What happens when you compile and execute this? Errors? Weird results? What?

Comment: What is the output you expect, and what are you getting? I'm pretty sure that in x++ * x++ and ++y*++y* it's undefined whether the first increment has happened by the time the second one is evaluated, so the value you get will vary from environment to environment

Comment: In your original question, there was a typo (`#deifne` instead of `#define`) I corrected now, make sure the code you use is correct.

Answer (score 16):

The result of an expression with more than one ++ operator on the same variable is officially an **undefined behavior** in C.

Comment: Is this technically "undefined behavior"?  I thought it was "unspecified behavior", which is still bad, but limits the implementation to certain choices (which in this case do not include crashing).

Comment: Yes, it's definitely undefined ;).

Comment: By the way, this answer is not exactly correct. An expression may modify the same variable multiple times - the behavior is undefined only if between these modifications there is no sequence point (i.e. &&, ||, ?:, comma operator or function call)

Comment: A language lawyer I'm not :) Nor do I play one on TV.

Answer (score 7):

`#define` is an instruction to the preprocessor to literally replace each occurrence of the macro with its expansion. So the relevant lines in your code will pass to the compiler as:

```
b1 = a1++ * a1++;
b2 = ++a2 * ++a2;
```

As Seva states, these expressions are officially undefined; but even if we take what is arguably the most sensible reading you'll still get `b1 = 2 * 3;` and `b2 = 3 * 4;` (with both `a1` and `a2` set to 4 after the lines.

Answer (score 3):

Both uses of SQ invoke undefined behaviour, as they are assigning to a1 and a2 more than once per sequence point. You should not pass expressions with side effects such as assignments or increments to macros.

Answer (score 2):

because define just replaces the expression. so you get in result:

```
b1 = (a1++)*(a1++);
b2 = (++a2)*(++a2;
```

So, you get double increment twice. It results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: You added some parentheses to the expansion.  That doesn't make any difference in this case, but sometimes it makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Darron Agree with you. For sake of readability here.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations! You have just discovered why it is a *bad idea* to use macros for this sort of thing. As a general rule, only make something a macro if it *cannot* be done using a function. In this case, `SQ` could easily be implemented as a function instead:

```
int sq (int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a more important point than C++ language arcana

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the operands in the macro between parenthesis:

```
#define SQ(X) (X)*(X)
```

Also, try not to operate with x++ and x in the same assignment. Could lead to undefined behavior.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
b1 = SQ(a1++);
b2 = SQ(++a2);
```

expand to

```
b1 = a1++ * a1++;
b2 = ++a2 * ++a2;
```

which invoke undefined behavior (an object may have its value modified at most once between sequence points), meaning *any* result is considered "correct".

That's the problem with these sorts of macros; you really want the argument to be evaluated *once*, but because of the expansion it gets evaluated twice.

There's also the problem with calling it with an expression like

```
x = SQ(a + b);
```

This will expand to

```
x = a + b * a + b;
```

which is probably not what you wanted.  To preserve operator precedence, the expansion should be wrapped in `()`, such as

```
#define SQ(x) (x) * (x)
```

Comment: Re your last point, you also need to wrap the whole expression in parentheses i.e. `#define SQ(x) ((x) * (x))` otherwise expressions like `x = -SQ(4)` might give unexpected results.

Comment: @JeremyP: oops, yes, you're right.  Can you tell I don't use macros like this a lot?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code as it will be expanded by the preprocessor:

```
b1 = a1++ * a1++;
b2 = ++a2 * ++a2;
```

This is undefined behavior, because you are modifying a variable more than once without a sequence point between them.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what your question is, but maybe you have problems with your expected output...
Be aware that `#define` is a "simple" text-replacement that is running before your code compiles.
This text-replacement has no respect for scope or syntactic correctnes.. it just replaces anything that matches with what you said it.
In your case it would not really make a square of the result of "a++", instead it would
generate this code: b1 = a++ * a++;

If you look here: [Question about C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993766/question-about-c-programming) you can see some explanations as why "a++ * a++" is officially undefined behaviour.